# What are the photo gallery/album module choices?

Tags: 7, media

I am looking to make a Flickr like site that user can create albums, upload photos.
With Drupal 6, this can be easily done by CCK, Node Reference, Views.

For Drupal 7, it seems difficult since Node Reference is not available yet. (There is a module called Reference, but it only has a development snapshot release.)

So are there any modules that can achieve the ugc photo albums functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An album essentially is a grouping of like nodes.

In drupal this grouping can be done a number of ways. I would suggest using a fixed taxonomy (not free tagging) for the album. This way views can list list all photos (nodes) from a particular tag and you can create thumbnails for instance for display.

You could also group by author for another group of nodes (e.g. 'my photos')

Answer (score 5):

There's the [Media Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_gallery) module. Haven't used it so I'm not sure how good its Views integration is. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> Uses the [Media module](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) to provide a rich media gallery. It currently supports images and YouTube videos well. Other file types may or may not work as well, but the facility is there to add them.

Comment: I tried media_gallery, but it requires some modules that I can't find:  File_styles, Multiplatform.

Answer (score 1):

[Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/cck_field_perms) should be able to do it.

I am using the 7.x version; I have not used it to set View Own content, but to block others from viewing it. It should be viable, though.  Use this with a content type and an image field module of your choice and it might do what you want it to do.